# Getting a list of substring based unique filenames in an array

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory `my_dir` with files having names like:

```
a_v5.json
a_v5.mapping.json
a_v5.settings.json
f_v39.json
f_v39.mapping.json
f_v39.settings.json
f_v40.json
f_v40.mapping.json
f_v40.settings.json
c_v1.json
c_v1.mapping.json
c_v1.settings.json
```

I'm looking for a way to get an array `[a_v5, f_v40, c_v1]` in bash. Here, array of file names with the latest version number is what I need.

Tried this: `ls *.json | find . -type f -exec basename "{}" \; | cut -d. -f1`, but it returns the results with files which are not of the .json extension.

Comment: @anubhava Updated the OP.

Comment: Regarding your command: `ls | find` is the same as just `find`. `find` does not read stdin. To list only `json` files use `find . -type f -iname \*.json`.

Comment: @Socowi How about getting the unique file name based on the number? Any suggestions on that?

Comment: `[a_v5, f_v40, c_v1]` is the expected output.

Comment: "array of file names with latest version number" is what I precisely mean. Apologies for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command if your filenames don't contain whitespace and special symbols like `*` or `?`:

```
array=($(
    find . -type f -iname \*.json |
    sed -E 's|(.*/)*(.*_v)([0-9]+)\..*|\2 \3|' |
    sort -Vr | sort -uk1,1 | tr -d ' '
))
```

It's ugly and unsafe. The following solution is longer but can handle all file names, even those with linebreaks in them.

```
maxversions() {
    find -type f -iname \*.json -print0 |
    gawk 'BEGIN { RS = "\0"; ORS = "\0" }
        match($0, /(.*\/)*(.*_v)([0-9]+)\..*/, group) {
            prefix = group[2];
            version = group[3];
            if (version > maxversion[prefix])
                maxversion[prefix] = version
        }
        END {
            for (prefix in maxversion)
                print prefix maxversion[prefix]
        }'
}
mapfile -d '' array < <(maxversions)
```

In both cases you can check the contents of `array` with `declare -p array`.

Comment: With this, I get `sed: 1: "s/|(.*/)*(.*_v)([0-9]+) ...": RE error: empty (sub)expression`. None of my file names have spaces in them, btw.

Comment: My bad. That's what I get for making some changes without checking first :( . Could you try again.

Comment: That works! (with a small modification though, i.e. removing the leading and trailing parentheses on the right-hand side of the array assignment). One last thing: Is your solution supposed to work when there are multiple underscores in the file name?

Comment: I think so. But please don't use it in production. The `awk` command should be finished soon and should work in every case.

Comment: Since my file names are not going to have any spaces or special characters, I'd like to go ahead with the first solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to handle multiple underscores in the file names with the first solution?

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure multiple underscores are no problem. Both solutions should handle them correctly. If you have multiple `_v12.` then the version in the file name before the *first* dot will be used. Example: In `some/path_v1.dir/file_v2._v3.json` the version `v2` will be used. `v1` and `v3` are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and bash string parsing.

```
declare -A tmp=()
for f in $SOURCE_DIR/*.json
do f=${f##*/}        # strip path
   tmp[${f%%.*}]=1   # strip extraneous data after . in filename
done
declare -a c=( $( printf "%s\n" "${!tmp[@]}" | cut -c 1 | sort -u ) ) # get just the first chars
declare -a lst=( $( for f in "${c[@]}"
                    do printf "%s\n" "${!tmp[@]}" |
                         grep "^${f}_"            |
                         sort -n                  |
                         tail -1; done ) )
echo "[ ${lst[@]} ]"
[ a_v5 c_v1 f_v40 ]
```

Or, if you'd rather,

```
declare -a arr=( $(
  for f in $SOURCE_DIR/*.json
  do d=${f%/*}         # get dir path
     f=${f##*/}        # strip path
     g=${f:0:2}        # get leading str
     ( cd $d && printf "%s\n" ${g}*.json | 
       sort -n | sed -n '$ { s/[.].*//; p; }' )
  done | sort -u ) )
echo "[ ${arr[@]} ]"
[ a_v5 c_v1 f_v40 ]
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this would possibly solve my problem.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to specify json files. This should create the array you needed, though it will have both the `f_v39` & `f_v40`'s.

Comment: Okay. I need just the file name with the largest/latest version number in it. Do you see any way to filter it out?

Comment: Misunderstood. Give me a bit.

Comment: Okay. With your code, I get `syntax error: operand expected`. Do you get that too?

Comment: Nope. Which line?

Comment: With your latest code, I get the same error at line `for f in ${SOURCE_DIR}*.json; do tmp[${f%%.*}]=1; done`.

Comment: You need to be able to prepend a path. That changes things. Give me a few.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way to accomplish this :

```
arr=( $(  { for name in $( ls {f,n,m}*.txt );  do echo ${name:0:1} ; done; } | sort | uniq ) )
```

#### Output :

```
$ echo ${arr[0]}
f

$ echo ${arr[1]}
m

$ echo ${arr[2]}
n
```

Regards!

Comment: Instead of `$( ls {f,n,m}*.txt` you can write just `{f,n,m}*.txt`. The latter is not only shorter, but also way safer and faster. Also, why `txt`? All files in OP's example end with `json`.

Comment: I donwvoted because this doesn't answer the question. Even if this solution was what OP asked for it would only work with single letter base names like `a_v1.json`  but not `abc_v1.json`. I would appreciate it if you could either fix or delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

### AWK SOLUTION

This is not an elegant solution... my knowledge of awk is limited.
You should find this functional.

I've updated this to remove the obsolete uniq as suggested by @socowi.
I've also included the printf version as @socowi suggested.

```
ls *.json | cut -d. -f1 | sort -rn |  awk -v last="xx" '$1 !~ last{ print $1; last=substr($1,1,3)  }'
```

OR

```
printf %s\\n *.json | cut -d. -f1 | sort -rn | awk -v last="xx" '$1 !~ last{ print $1; last=substr($1,1,3)  }'
```

---

Old understanding below

Find files with name matching pattern.

Now take the second field since your results will likely be similar to ./

```
find . -type f -iname "*.json" | cut -d. -f2
```

To get the unique headings....

```
find . -type f -iname "*.json" | cut -d. -f2 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: This did not give me the expected output. It instead gave me `settings mapping json ...`

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure your environment may be different than my own. If you're getting settings, mapping and json you may indeed need -f1.

Comment: Even with that (`find . -type f -iname "*.json" | cut -d. -f1 | sort | uniq`), I did not get the expected output since all the file names, when considered with version, would always be unique.

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure Another method is to not use find at all.

    ls *.json | cut -d. -f1 | sort | uniq

Comment: I missed the part about version numbers. My apologies

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure, Instead of giving up... I've altered my solution to use AWK. given the filename samples above (and adding a few extra) this gets the correct items on my system.

Comment: Some improvements: Replace `ls *.json` by `printf %s\\n *.json` and I think `uniq` is not necessary anymore. `substr($1,1,3)` will only work for file names of the form `a_v##` where `a` is *exactly one* letter.

Comment: Got errors and did not get desired output through any of the suggestions. :(